# Delphi's TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars() always return an empty string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

With Delphi XE4, try the following code:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myStr: string;
begin
  Edit1.Text := TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars('test');
end;
```

The result (`Edit1.Text`) is empty.

Is this a bug or I'm missing something? I previously had no problem with this `TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars` function with the version from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) pre-DelphiXE.

**Update 2**: Just upgrading an app written in D2010 and encountering this bug, but just wondering how such an obvious bug can exist this long... now I'm seriously considering making my code compatible to **Free Pascal**, but I really like the antonymous method...

Update 1: I'm using Delphi XE4 Update 1.

Comment: Can you post the code from `TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars`. It's in `System.RegularExpressionsCore`. I don't have the source for XE4 to hand. Your code works fine in XE3. I wonder if they improved the code by using the new string helper methods and forgot that they return new values rather than modify existing ones.  By the way, as an aside, your SSCCE would be much better in a console app using `Writeln`.

Comment: @David: I've posted the original code (with a single line commented out) as part of my answer. You can get the XE4/XE5 version by uncommenting that line and removing the one that follows it. The bug exists in both XE4 and XE5.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, suggestion's accepted, next time I'll use WriteLn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug. If that's the case, both the XE4 and XE5 versions contain it. I've opened a [QC report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124091) to report it for XE4..XE6.

The problem appears to be with the last line of the function:

```
Result.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
```

Stepping through in the debugger shows that the `Tmp` (a TCharArray) correctly contains `'t','e','s','t', #0, #0, #0, #0` at that point, yet `Result` contains `''` when the function actually returns, as setting a breakpoint on the `end;` following that line indicates that result contains `''` at that point (and when the function returns).

Providing a replacement version in a class helper with a minor change to actually store the return value from the call to `Create` fixes the problem:

```
type
  TPerlRegExHelper = class helper for TPerlRegEx
  public
    class function EscapeRegExCharsEx(const S: string): string; static;
  end;

class function TPerlRegExHelper.EscapeRegExCharsEx(const S: string): string;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Tmp: TCharArray;
begin
  SetLength(Tmp, S.Length * 2);
  J := 0;
  for I := Low(S) to High(S) do
  begin
    case S[I] of
      '.', '[', ']', '(', ')', '?', '*', '+', '{', '}', '^', '$', '|', '\':
        begin
          Tmp[J] := '\';
          Inc(j);
          Tmp[J] := S[I];
        end;
      #0:
        begin
          Tmp[J] := '\';
          Inc(j);
          Tmp[J] := '0';
        end;
      else
        Tmp[J] := S[I];
    end;
    Inc(J);
  end;
  { Result.Create(Tmp, 0, J); }  // The problem code from the original
  Result := String.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
end;
```

The XE3 (and the open-source version you mention) implement the logic totally differently, using the more standard manipulation of `Result` beginning at the first line of the function with `Result := S;`, and then using `System.Insert` as needed to add room for the escape characters.

Comment: @David: OK. It's a bug I can confirm but not explain - as I said, "appears to be" AFAICT. Can you explain the issue, and why my fix works? (Not arguing - asking for information.) It appears that the class static returns a new value that is immediately discarded before the function returns, according to the debugger.

Comment: Ken and David, actually I got around the problem using the open source version of EscapeRegExChars(), but it doesn't remove my appreciation toward your help and my admiration to you knowledgable guys! Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in the XE4 release that is still present in XE6. Previous versions were fine. It looks like the changes were made in readiness for some future switch to immutable strings.

Rather ironically the bug is caused by the string never being assigned a value at all. It's one thing to set out not to mutate a string, but quite another never to initialize it!

So to the analysis of the bug. The method in question in `TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars` defined in the `System.RegularExpressionsCore` unit. This is a class function that returns a string. Its signature is:

```
class function EscapeRegExChars(const S: string): string;
```

The XE4 implementation makes but one reference to the result variable. As follows:

```
Result.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
```

Here, `Tmp` is an array of `char` containing the escaped text to be returned, and `J` is the length of that text.

So, it seems clear that the author intended for this code to assign to the function return variable `Result`. Sadly that does not occur. Why not? Well, the `Create` method being called is defined in the helper for `string`. This is `TStringHelper` defined in the `System.SysUtils` unit. There are three `Create` overloads and the one in play here is:

```
class function Create(const Value: array of Char; StartIndex: Integer; 
  Length: Integer): string; overload; static;
```

Note that this is a class static function. That means that it is not an instance method and has no `Self` pointer. So when called like this:

```
Result.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
```

It is simply a function call whose return value is ignored. It might appear that the result variable would be set but remember that this `Create` is a class static method. It therefore has no instance. The compiler simply uses the type of `Result` to resolve the method. The code is equivalent to:

```
string.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
```

Nothing more exciting than a call to a function whose return value is simply ignored. Defeated by the extended syntax that allows us to ignore function return values.

The fix to the code is simple enough. Replace that final line with

```
Result := string.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
```

You could apply the fix in a copy of the unit, and include that unit in your code. An alternative to that, my preferred option, is to use a code hook. Like this:

```
unit FixTPerlRegExEscapeRegExChars;

interface

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows, System.RegularExpressionsCore;

procedure PatchCode(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: Integer);
var
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(Address, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    Move(NewCode, Address^, Size);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, Address, Size);
    VirtualProtect(Address, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

procedure RedirectProcedure(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := NativeInt(NewAddress)-NativeInt(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  PatchCode(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

function EscapeRegExChars(Self: TPerlRegEx; const S: string): string;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Tmp: TCharArray;
begin
  SetLength(Tmp, S.Length * 2);
  J := 0;
  for I := Low(S) to High(S) do
  begin
    case S[I] of
      '.', '[', ']', '(', ')', '?', '*', '+', '{', '}', '^', '$', '|', '\':
        begin
          Tmp[J] := '\';
          Inc(j);
          Tmp[J] := S[I];
        end;
      #0:
        begin
          Tmp[J] := '\';
          Inc(j);
          Tmp[J] := '0';
        end;
      else
        Tmp[J] := S[I];
    end;
    Inc(J);
  end;
  Result := string.Create(Tmp, 0, J);
end;

initialization
  RedirectProcedure(@TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars, @EscapeRegExChars);

end.
```

Add this unit to your project and the calls to `TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars` will start working again.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.RegularExpressionsCore,
  FixTPerlRegExEscapeRegExChars in 'FixTPerlRegExEscapeRegExChars.pas';

begin
  Writeln(TPerlRegEx.EscapeRegExChars('test'));
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
test
```

[QC#124091](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124091)

Comment: The QC report has been submitted. #124091. (I submitted it earlier, when I saw that the bug still exists in the new release of XE6.

Comment: @ken thanks. I've linked to it. I wrote this answer to address your questions in the comments to your answer. And to provide future visitors with a hook based solution.